# Lodash transform arguments via typescript definition

Tags: typescript, transform, lodash

I am working with typescript + lodash and I want to use the **transform** method for the lodash

But I have stucked with the typescript definitions for this method. Could someone help me please?

Here is my attempts to resolve this issue

Here is the possible source object that I want to handle 
top level fields can have any name and be multiple. There is only one static structure - nesting + fields/transitions fields at the and.

I want to create the same object but without *transition* for every property and I have found that the transform is fine to achieve this goal.

P.S Updated with the example os use

```
import { transform } from 'lodash';

 let a = {
  avalanche: {
    boze: {
      fields: {
        content_0: 0,
        content_1: 1
      },
      transition: {
        content_0: 0,
        content_1: 1
      }
    }
  },
  blizzard: {
    conica: {
      fields: {
        content_0: 0,
        content_1: 1
      },
      transition: {
        content_0: 0,
        content_1: 1
      }
    }
  }
};

type StatusPermission = HashMap<number>;

type RolePermission = HashMap<StatusPermission>;

type Permissions = HashMap<RolePermission>;    


interface IPermissionsContent {
  [ key: string ]: number;
}

interface IPermRolesContent {
  fields: IPermissionsContent;
  transitions: IPermissionsContent;
}

interface ISourcePermissions<T> {
  [ key: string ]: T;
}

interface ISourcePermissionsRoles<T> extends ISourcePermissions<T> {
  [ key: string ]: T;
}

export function aggregatePermissions(sourcePermissions: ISourcePermissions<ISourcePermissionsRoles<IPermRolesContent>>): Permissions {
  return transform(sourcePermissions, aggregatePermissionsCore, ({} as ISourcePermissionsRoles<IPermRolesContent> | Permissions ));
}

function aggregatePermissionsCore(resultPermissions: ISourcePermissionsRoles<IPermRolesContent> | Permissions,
                                      val: ISourcePermissionsRoles<IPermRolesContent> | IPermRolesContent, key: string): void {
      let res: Permissions | undefined = val['fields'];
      if (!res) {
        res = transform(val, aggregatePermissionsCore, {});
      }
      resultPermissions[key] = res;

    }

    let res = aggregatePermissions(a);

    console.log('a => ', res);
```

// a is:

```
{
  avalanche: {
    boze: {
        content_0: 0,
        content_1: 1
    }
  },
  blizzard: {
    conica: 
        content_0: 0,
        content_1: 1
    }
  }
};
```

**The errors**
First one to this line:
*'return transform(sourcePermissions, aggregatePermissionsCore, ({} as ISourcePermissionsRoles | Permissions ));'*

```
Argument of type 'HashMap<HashMap<HashMap<number>>> | ISourcePermissionsRoles<IPermRolesContent>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HashMap<HashMap<number>>[]'.
  Type 'HashMap<HashMap<HashMap<number>>>' is not assignable to type 'HashMap<HashMap<number>>[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type 'HashMap<HashMap<HashMap<number>>>'.
```

The second one to this line:

*resultPermissions[key] = res;*

```
Type 'HashMap<HashMap<HashMap<number>>>' is not assignable to type 'HashMap<HashMap<number>> | IPermRolesContent'.
  Type 'HashMap<HashMap<HashMap<number>>>' is not assignable to type 'IPermRolesContent'.
    Property 'fields' is missing in type 'HashMap<HashMap<HashMap<number>>>'
```

Comment: Your example is not easily compliable, and as I tried to fix the errors I get a similar but different error to yours. Could you please post a complete working sample that reproduces the problem ?

Comment: Sure, hope it helps =\

Comment: I just used any for all of these stuff. I just can't understand why it's so hard to work with lodash and typescript =\

Comment: Sorry I gave up, I don't receive your errors and the example if you copy paste it in a new file and install the latest lodash does not compile. I am sure it can be made to work but your example is incomplete ..